# Python Tkinter: ¿Como obtengo el texto del objeto seleccionado en un OptionMenu?

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy haciendo un editor de texto y quiero hacer un menu desplegable con el OptionMenu para elejir la fuente que desees (nunca use un OptionMenu)

Primero, cree el `Text` para que el usuario pueda escribir (en principio la fuente empieza en Arial):

```
input = Text(window, width=98, height=20, font=("Arial", 15))
input.pack(fill=X)
input.place(y=35)
```

Entonces, declare una variable llamada `var`:

```
window = Tk()
var = StringVar(window)
```

Luego, cree el OptionMenu y una lista llamada fonts:

```
fonts = ["Arial", "Impact", "Times New Roman", "Comic Sans MS", "Georgia", "Trebuchet MS", 
"Verdana"]
fontchooserB = OptionMenu(window, var, *fonts).place(x=100)
```

Despues cree una funcion llamada `setFont()`, que se encargaria de obtener la variable `var` y establecerla como fuente del `Text` y se activaria cuando la ventana detecte movimiento en el cursor

```
def setFont(event):
    input.config(font=(str(var), 15))

window.bind("<B1-Motion>", setFont)
window.mainloop()
```

Lo ejecuto y no funciona el OptionMenu, es lo unico que no funciona, pero al principio empieza en blanco:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y si lo cambio a "Impact" por ejemplo no funciona, no aparece ningun error (Si Tkinter no reconoce una fuente pone la predeterminada, osea Arial) pero no funciona en ninguna fuente

Probe imprimir en pantalla la variable `var` y aparecio esto:

```
PY_VAR0
```

Entonces llegue a la conclusion que no es que "no funcione", parece que el valor que devuelve es algo que no es "Arial", "Times New Roman" o algo asi.

¿Que hago para que funcione correctamente?

Saludos.

Comment: Lo que estás obteniendo al imprimir var NO es el contenido de la variable, si no el nombre de la variable. El StringVar es una variable de control. Lee este link para entender las variables de control y hayarás la solución por ti mismo: https://python-para-impacientes.blogspot.com/2016/02/variables-de-control-en-tkinter.html

Comment: Gracias! Si quieres puedes ponerlo como respuesta y te marco respuesta correcta